# Prevent SQL injection when SQL is supplied from the request

Tags: sql, rest, sql-injection

The company I am working at uses a REST API for database accesses. So basically, you just provide a SQL statement string and the REST API returns a Datatable. Now I am unsure as to how to prevent an SQL injection as I cannot generate the SQL command using parameters (as I normally would) since I have to provide a SQL statement string for the REST API.

Comment: How are you executing that query? I mean is it a `select` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make this safe is to **whitelist** a specific list of SQL queries that are pre-vetted. The REST API would compare the input to the whitelist. If the SQL query is one of the known queries in the whitelist, then it can run. Otherwise, the API returns an error status (I'd use 400 BAD REQUEST).

But I suppose the purpose of the API is to run *any* SQL statement the client inputs, verbatim. This is literally an SQL injection vulnerability by design. There is no way to make that not SQL injection.

Besides that, the API really goes against the conventions of a RESTful web service.

- The URI of the request doesn't identify the resource.
- I assume every request is a POST with the SQL query as a payload. You probably don't use http methods like PUT, PATCH, or DELETE.
- The message in response, being only a datatable, isn't self-descriptive; it doesn't contain metadata the client can use to manipulate the resource.
- SQL, being a generative grammar, allows an unlimited variety of queries. This doesn't fit the HATEOAS principle that the REST server should be able to describe the valid actions on request. The client must have implicit knowledge of your database schema.

You don't have a REST API. You have a web service with no specific interface.

The presence of a "query anything" API should be a huge red flag. It's probably a sign that the project isn't specified well in other ways.